# Method Of Moments problem

Tags: probability-theory

Consider an r.v $X$ such that $E(X^k)$ is finite for all $k$. In addition if $Y$ is another r.v. such that $E(X^k)=E(Y^k)$ for all $k$, then $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$. \

Suppose $(X_n)_n$ satisfies $E(X_n^k)<\infty$ for all $n,k\ge 1$ and $E(X_n^k)\to E(X^k)$. I am trying to show that $X_n\to X$ in distribution.

However, using the continuity theorem we have that

$\lim_n \varphi_{X_n}(t)=\lim_n\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}E(X_n^k)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}E(X^k)=\varphi_X(t)$.

and the result is proved. where did we need the fact that if $X$ is determined by it's moments, then its distribution is unique?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the way the question should have been phrased is:

> Suppose  $X$ is a random variable such that, firstly, $m_k=E[X^k]$ is finite for all $k$ and such that, secondly, there is only one probability measure   $\mu$ (namely the distribution of $X$) such that $\int_{\mathbb R} x^k \mu(dx) = m_k$ for all $k$.  If $X_n$ is a sequence of rvs such that for each $k$, we have $E[X_n^k]\to m_k$, does it follow that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$?

As the other answer correctly points out, the OP's attempted characteristic function proof fails, because the finiteness of the $m_k$ does not imply the series  $\sum_{k\ge0} m_n (it)^k/k!$ converges.  This argument does not use the second part of the assumption, that the law of $X$ is uniquely determined by the sequence $m_k$.

With this assumption, however, the result is fairly easy. (See
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(probability_theory)), [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Moments,_method_of_(in_probability_theory)), or the references [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724007/the-ratio-of-moments-in-a-normal-distribution/3724023#3724023).)  Here is a sketch of an argument:  Let $\mu_n$ be the distribution of $X_n$.  Since $\lim E[X_n^2]=m_2$ we know that the family of probability measures $\mu_n$ is tight, and hence any subsequence of the $\mu_n$ has a sub sub sequence converging to some probability distribution, call it $\nu$.  For each $k$ observe that the family of rvs $X_n^k$ is uniformly integrable,  since $E[X_n^{2+2k}]\to m_{2+2k}<\infty$. Hence $\int_{\mathbb R} x^k \mu_n(dx)\to \int_{\mathbb R} x^k\nu(dx)$, and so $\int_{\mathbb R} x^k\nu(dx)=m_k$.  But by the second, or uniquely determined, hypothesis, $\nu$ must be equal to $\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

All you know about $E[X_n^k]$ is that it is finite.  The assumptions you're given don't allow you to assert that the series $\sum_{k\ge 0} (it)^k E[X_n^k]/k!$ or
$\sum_{k\ge 0} (it)^k E[X^k]/k!$ converge for any nonzero $t$, let alone that the limit of the first as $n \to \infty$ is the second.

Comment: I thought if the moments exist, we can represent the c.f. in this series format? do you have an idea how to proceed with this problem then?

Comment: The OP's second sentence seems to assume  that the law of $X$ is uniquely determined by its moment sequence.  If so, the sequence $X_n$ is tight, and any limit distribution has the same moments as that of $X$, and hence must the the distribution of $X$. See the discussion in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724007/the-ratio-of-moments-in-a-normal-distribution/3724023#3724023 .